Is the $4k used Electric Vehicle tax credit reducing or inflating car prices?
I've been watching the prices of used Tesla Model 3s and I'm noticing a lot of those eligible for the Used Electric Vehicle tax credit seem to have prices right under $25,000, which is the maximum selling price allowed to claim the credit.
It got me to thinking: how is this credit actually influencing the market for these cars? Obviously getting the credit would make a big difference for a buyer, but if the credit wasn't available wouldn't the market reflect that through lower prices?
For example: assume two comparable cars are for sale, one through a dealer who is eligible through the IRS guidelines, and the other from a private seller. The buyer would be motivated to purchase the car from the dealer, even if paying $3,999 more than the price offered by the private seller.
But if the credit were not available, the private sale would be better.
At the end of the day, is this $4k credit artificially propping up the price of these cars?
